# How to check if @Grab loaded jars? Script throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jdbc, groovy

**Groovy version**: 2.0.8

I'm trying to write a script that get the Oracle JDBC driver from a private maven repository (no authentication required):

```
package main.groovy

import groovy.sql.Sql

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

@GrabResolver(name='oracle', root='http://my-local-server:8082/maven/repo/')
@Grapes([
@Grab('com.oracle:oracle:11.1.0.7.0'),
@Grab('com.oracle:i18n:10.2.0.5')
])
class FrameworkInspector {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        //NullPointerException
        //this.class.classLoader.getURLs().each{
        //    ClassLoader.systemClassLoader.addURL(it);
        //}

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

        java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid", "user", "pwd");

        Sql sql = new Sql(connection)
        println sql.firstRow("select * from dual")

    }
}
```

How can I check if my jar's are loaded? Currently I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a classloader issue, try adding `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)` like so:

```
package main.groovy

@GrabResolver(name='oracle', root='http://my-local-server:8082/maven/repo/')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('com.oracle:oracle:11.1.0.7.0')
@Grab('com.oracle:i18n:10.2.0.5')

import groovy.sql.Sql

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

class FrameworkInspector {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        //NullPointerException
        //this.class.classLoader.getURLs().each{
        //    ClassLoader.systemClassLoader.addURL(it);
        //}

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

        java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid", "user", "pwd");

        Sql sql = new Sql(connection)
        println sql.firstRow("select * from dual")

    }
}
```

Comment: This works in groovy console, but if I run through Eclipse I get "No suitable ClassLoader found for grab". I need something else to run in the IDE?

Comment: @SérgioMichels Is this Java 8 or OpenJDK?  There are issues with Grab in those :-/  For a "proper" project, I'd recommend downloading the relevant jars and adding them to your classpath (or adding them as `runtime` dependencies if you're doing a gradle/maven build), and go with that...  Grab is brilliant for quick scripts, but outside of that I'd go the well trodden route

Comment: Nope, I'm using Oracle JDK 1.6.0_45. But thanks for the tip, I will go with adding those jars in the classpath.